# Unable to create schema column of field named 'timestamp' from firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, import, google-bigquery, schema

I am trying to import data from firestore into BigQuery and I am able to convert the data into schema properly, but I have only one problem [Collection Users, I have one field named as timestamp and the datatype is also timestamp] I am unable to convert this field into column by specifying it in the schema file.But when I changed the field name to utime I get access to it in BigQuery...
Can anyone guide, I already have many registered users in the collection and I am searching for alternate way in which it wont be required to modify the fieldname in the firestore.
[screenshot of my firestore db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu5PQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timestamp is a reserved word. You can escape it by surrounding it with backticks. This will allow you to select a column that uses a reserved word for a name, or to alias a column with a reserved word.